Strange behaviour of audit
In first questions review, I've downvoted the following question and I got:

What's wrong to downvote such a question?

was flagging an option? You should flag, not downvote spam

@JourneymanGeek: I don't remember if flag option was present. I wasn't aware that flag spam is mandatory but OK.

@Toto Flagging is absolutely an option for the First Questions queue. Downvoting spam just makes it less visible to lower rep users, potentially hiding it from people who would take the correct action by flagging it, and is less desirable than flagging. Commenting and downvoting are definitely less useful than flagging spam as spam on this particular post.

It's an annoying part of the audit system.
